# Upload .tex File to Overleaf

Tags: upload, overleaf

I'm uploading a .tex file using overleaf. The upload seems to be unproblematic (I can rename and download the document and I can see the content). Problems arise when I want to edit the document. This is not possible. I cannot modify the symbols and the font is gray. Do you know what could have happened?

Comment: you could ask the overleaf support